# Decode audio from a credit card reader

Tags: linux, audio, credit-card

I got a credit card reader that plugs into the microphone jack from my bank, and they provide apps for android and MacOS to receive payments this way. I don’t have any of these systems nor the need to accept payments, but I am curious about the device. I can record the sound on my laptop. So: Is there a Linux program that can decode this signal?

Comment: Found a C library here, but did not get it to read the Data I have: https://github.com/ieatlint/mslib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the other answers I found the right words to search for and found [mslib](https://github.com/ieatlint/mslib) via [the authors blog](http://blog.tehinterweb.com/?p=117) and, after [some adjustments](https://github.com/nomeata/mslib/commit/c4ae2aa876cab51d8d69e885d2313e2e96ef79fd), got it to read data from my reader.

The library comes with a small test program that can read files created by:

```
arecord  -c 1 -N -r48000 -f S16_LE -i -v
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably doing the same thing as the Square [audio-input based card readers](http://cosmodro.me/blog/2011/mar/25/rhombus-square-iskewedi/); using the equivalent of a tape head to read the information as audio. Someone has written some code that's [available on GitHub](https://github.com/sshipman/RhombusLib) for decoding this data.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I’ll have a look, but it might not be easy to get it to run outside an android environment.